# How is a field without commutative multiplication called?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I find it very useful to use the structure in my work and I'd like to know its name, if it has one. I don't seem to find it.

Comment: I've heard that called a "skew field". Ex the quaternions.

Comment: skew field? division algebra?

Comment: It is often called "division ring". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring

Comment: Both are used. In France, the word ‘corps’ is used for both, and a field is said to be a ‘corps commutatif’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "division ring" is the best, but "skew field," sometimes abbreviated to 'sfield', is another established term.

In some older literature, you may find "field" to be used for "noncommutative fields" too. That is not standard practice nowadays.

I would avoid "division algebra" because that term is sometimes used without assuming associativity.

Comment: This is still sometimes applies in modern french literature.

Comment: @flawr by “this” are you referring to using “field “ for noncomutative fields?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, yes that is what I mean. ["Corps"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corps_(math%C3%A9matiques)) does not necessarily define whether the multiplication is commutative or not, and you use the terms ["corps commutatif"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corps_commutatif) for *field* or ["corps gauche"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corps_gauche) for *skew field*.

Comment: @flawr I thought this was the case, but didn’t feel confident asserting so. Thanks for chipping in with the information.